# Remove KMZ Layer from google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hello I am trying to remove kmz layer from google maps.

I have the function displayLayer, which set the map to null if param is false

then I set the map to current google map otherwise I set the map to null.

When I am setting the map to null, it doesn't disappear but rather stays.

I am trying to understand this behavior but I don't find the right reason for that behavior.

```
function displayLayer(isDisplayLayer) {
                var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6SG3MFSYw7dSk1ma3B3akVzdFk', {
                    suppressInfoWindows: true,
                    preserveViewport: false,
                });
                if (isDisplayLayer) {
                    alert('set map to gmap');
                    kmzLayer.setMap(gmap);
                } else {
                    alert('set map to null');
                    kmzLayer.setMap(null);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please help me ... I need answers. I have tried many times with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the map of a new `KmlLayer` that you are creating every time that the `displayLayer` function is called. You can put your `kmzLayer` creation for example on your `initMap`:

```
var map;
var kmzLayer;

function displayLayer(isDisplayLayer) {
    if (isDisplayLayer) {
        alert('set map to gmap');
        kmzLayer.setMap(map);
    } else {
        alert('set map to null');
        kmzLayer.setMap(null);
    }
}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: {lat: -36.90927416, lng: 174.84809875},
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: true,
        zoomControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6SG3MFSYw7dSk1ma3B3akVzdFk', {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        preserveViewport: true,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `KmlLayer` everytime, whether it exists already or not.

If it already exists don't recreate it, show or hide it.

```
var kmzLayer;

function displayLayer(isDisplayLayer) {
  if (!kmzLayer) {
    // initialize global variable
    kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6SG3MFSYw7dSk1ma3B3akVzdFk', {
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      preserveViewport: false,
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(kmzLayer, "status_changed", function() {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "KmlStatus=" + kmzLayer.getStatus();
    });
  }
  if (isDisplayLayer) {
    console.log('set map to gmap');
    kmzLayer.setMap(gmap);
  } else {
    console.log('set map to null');
    kmzLayer.setMap(null);
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kL1753db/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var gmap;

function initialize() {
  gmap = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  displayLayer(true);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var kmzLayer;

function displayLayer(isDisplayLayer) {
  if (!kmzLayer) {
    kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6SG3MFSYw7dSk1ma3B3akVzdFk', {
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      preserveViewport: false,
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(kmzLayer, "status_changed", function() {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "KmlStatus=" + kmzLayer.getStatus();
    });
  }
  if (isDisplayLayer) {
    console.log('set map to gmap');
    kmzLayer.setMap(gmap);
  } else {
    console.log('set map to null');
    kmzLayer.setMap(null);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="status"></div>
<input id="btn" type="button" onclick="displayLayer(false)" value="hide" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```